# how to use openCV as a motion detector (not looking for video output)

Tags: c++, opencv, sensors, motion-detection

I'm very new to c++ and have been doing a lot of research into openCV. 
I'm currently making a motion detector using a webcam and trying to use it to trigger a function (kind of like a listener). I don't need any kind of visual video in my application. I just need to sense motion and give an output like a boolean for instance.

I am much more familiar with java but it has to be written in c++, no wrappers, no converters.

Can someone please help point me in the write direction. maybe with a tutorial or suggestion of something I should look up. Even a different library I should use rather than openCV.

Comment: If I understood you correctly, you want to use a video processing framework to detect motion but without video?

Comment: yes. basically I need to detect motion through a window. I'm not using the video. I just need to trigger my device to go from sleep mode to awake mode when it detects motion.

Comment: I don't think its possible to achieve what you want.. You need some sort of input or sensor feed to run some analysis to determine motion or not.. If you don't want to use video, then use some sort of [motion sensor](https://www.safewise.com/resources/motion-sensor-guide).

Comment: Motion sensors wont work through glass. (radio sensors will but that's out of the question) infrared rays get reflected off the glass from PIR sensors and ultrasonic sensors bounce back from the glass.

Comment: Why can't u use video?

Comment: I can use it, I just meant that I don't necessarily need tracking. I just need to detect motion. If I use video it can be in the background and not displayed.

Comment: I thought you meant you **CAN'T** use video. If you can, use image subtraction for starters. Grab a frame, then have an infinite loop running where you grab another frame. Take the difference of the two, then update their values accordingly. If there's any difference between them, then you have *potential* movement going on

Comment: ok great Ill give that a try. thank you very much. Is there a way I can set the severity of the changes? basically so if something to far in the distance moves or changes that it wont constantly trigger a potential movement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a starting point, I'd recommend using a basic image subtraction then take it from there.

The basic algorithm is:

```
firstFrame = readFrame()

firstFrameGrey = convertToGreyScale(firstFrame) // makes the image B&W

while True

    secondFrame = readFrame()
    secondFrameGrey = convertToGreyScale(secondFrame)

    difference = sub(firstFrameGrey, secondFrameGrey)

    threshold()

    // perform some morphological operations
    erosion()
    dilation()

    findContours()

// loop over contours and try filtering based off of area, perimeter etc.
// This filtration will allow you to detect significant changes.

// update frame
firstFrameGrey = secondFrameGrey
```

For the morphological operations, experiment with different values and see what results you get.

More info on [thresholding](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/db/d8e/tutorial_threshold.html)

[This](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/db/df6/tutorial_erosion_dilatation.html) tutorial explains how to perform the morphological operations.

Contours info can be found [here](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/df/d0d/tutorial_find_contours.html) along with the [area API](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#contourarea)

The algorithm should be self explanatory and openCV has all the methods I named.